# Adapting a function that isnt chainable to return a value

Tags: javascript, pdf-reader

I am trying to get all the pages of a pdf in one object using the [pdfreader package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfreader). The function originally returns each page (as its own object) when it processes it. My goal is to write a wrapper that returns all pages as an array of page objects. Can someone explain why this didn't work?

**I tried**:

adding .then and a return condition - because I expected the parseFileItems method to return a value:

```
let pages = [];

new pdfreader.PdfReader()
  .parseFileItems(pp, function(err, item) {
    {
      if (!item) {
        return pages;
      } else if (item.page) {
        pages.push(lines);
        rows = {};
      } else if (item && item.text) {
        // accumulate text items into rows object, per line
        (rows[item.y] = rows[item.y] || []).push(item.text);
      }
    }
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("done" + pages.length);
  });
```

and got the error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

---

The function I'm modifying (From the package documentation):

```
var pdfreader = require("pdfreader");

var rows = {}; // indexed by y-position

function printRows() {
  Object.keys(rows) // => array of y-positions (type: float)
    .sort((y1, y2) => parseFloat(y1) - parseFloat(y2)) // sort float positions
    .forEach(y => console.log((rows[y] || []).join("")));
}

new pdfreader.PdfReader().parseFileItems("CV_ErhanYasar.pdf", function(
  err,
  item
) {
  if (!item || item.page) {
    // end of file, or page
    printRows();
    console.log("PAGE:", item.page);
    rows = {}; // clear rows for next page
  } else if (item.text) {
    // accumulate text items into rows object, per line
    (rows[item.y] = rows[item.y] || []).push(item.text);
  }
});
```

Comment: You seem to be expecting `parseFileItems()` to return a promise. It doesn't return anything, it just calls the callback function. You'll need to create your own promise if you want it to work that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be several issues/misconceptions at once here. Let's try to look at them once at a time.

Firstly, you seem to have thought that the outer function will return ("pass on") your callback's return value

This is not the case as you can see [in the library source](https://github.com/adrienjoly/npm-pdfreader/blob/d3f54f0e79177f4cd0e51581fb80faefcf24c01e/PdfReader.js#L44).

Also, it wouldn't even make sense, because the callback called once for each item. So, with 10 items, it will be invoked 10 times, and then how would `parseFileItems` know which of the 10 return values of your callback to pass to the outside?

It doesn't matter what you return from the callback function, as the `parseFileItems` function simply ignores it. Furthermore, the `parseFileItems` function itself doesn't return anything either. So, the result of `new pdfreader.parseFileItems(...)` will always evaluate to `undefined` (and `undefined` obviously has no property `then`).

Secondly, you seem to have thought that `.then` is some sort of universal chaining method for function calls.

In fact, `.then` is a way to chain *promises*, or to react on the fulfillment of a promise. In this case, there are no promises anywhere, and in particular `parseFileItems` doesn't returns a promise (it returns `undefined` as described above), so you cannot call `.then` on its result.

According to [the docs](https://github.com/adrienjoly/npm-pdfreader/#raw-pdf-reading), you are supposed to react on errors and the end of the stream yourself. So, your code would work like this:

```js
let pages = [];

new pdfreader.PdfReader()
  .parseFileItems(pp, function(err, item) {
    {
      if (!item) {
        // ****** Here we are done! ******
        console.log("done" + pages.length) // The code that was in the `then` goes here instead
      } else if (item.page) {
        pages.push(lines);
        rows = {};
      } else if (item && item.text) {
        // accumulate text items into rows object, per line
        (rows[item.y] = rows[item.y] || []).push(item.text);
      }
    }
  })
```

However, I agree that it'd be nicer to have a promise wrapper so that you won't have to stuff all the following code inside the callback's `if (!item)` branch. You could achieve that like this, using [`new Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise):

```js
const promisifiedParseFileItems = (pp, itemHandler) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  new pdfreader.PdfReader().parseFileItems(pp, (err, item) => {
    if (err) {
      reject(err)
    } else if (!item) {
      resolve()
    } else {
      itemHandler(item)
    }
  })
})

let pages = []

promisifiedParseFileItems(pp, item => {
  if (item.page) {
    pages.push(lines)
    rows = {}
  } else if (item && item.text) {
    // accumulate text items into rows object, per line
    (rows[item.y] = rows[item.y] || []).push(item.text)
  }
}).then(() => {
  console.log("done", pages.length)
}, e => {
  console.error("error", e)
})
```

*Note: You would get even nicer code with [async generators](https://jakearchibald.com/2017/async-iterators-and-generators/) but that is too much to explain here now, because the conversion from a callback to an async generator is less trivial than you may think.*

Comment: Your first example works great, but when I use the promisified version it never returns anything

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by that? Does it output `done 0`?

Comment: Oh I forgot to call `parseFileItems`, sorry! Updated my answer

Answer (score -1):

If you want to chain a `then`, you need the callback function to return a Promise :

```
new pdfreader.PdfReader()
    .parseFileItems(pp, function (err, item) {
        return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
            let pages = ...
            // do stuff
            resolve(pages);
        }
    })
    .then( pages => {
        console.log("done" + pages.length);
    });
```

Comment: Returning it from the callback won't necessarily make it be returned from `parseFileItems`! And as you can see in the [library source](https://github.com/adrienjoly/npm-pdfreader/blob/d3f54f0e79177f4cd0e51581fb80faefcf24c01e/PdfReader.js#L44), it indeed doesn't.